# Messages not delivered. No "send as text" option

Tags: iphone, messages, sms

I am not able to send or receive messages on iphone.  I get "not delivered" then "try again" but no option to "send as text". Worked fine until two days ago. MMS and SMS are on.

Comment: what iPhone (iPhone 4,5,6?) and what iOS version (9.3, 10.1...) are you using? Where are you located? (US/UK/...)

Answer (score 1):

Persistent *Not delivered* error usually is related to connectivity issues, so make sure you're connected to the internet, then double check your *iCloud* credentials by going to *Settings* and verify that you're logged in properly into your Apple ID account (you may also consider signing out and signing in again).

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**

Under `Cellular > Cellular Data Options > Voice & Data` try switching from LTE to 4G. If that does not help see steps which I took below before my SMS started to work.

---

I have US Mobile carrier and this article helped me solve this issue for my carrier:

https://usmobile.helpdocs.io/troubleshooting/i-cannot-send-or-receive-text-messages-with-gsm-lte-line

([Archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20220502184812/https://usmobile.helpdocs.io/troubleshooting/i-cannot-send-or-receive-text-messages-with-gsm-lte-line))

First, I updated my APN settings under Cellular > Cellular Data Network to these values:

https://www.apnsettings.org/us/us-mobile/ ([Archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20220502185312/https://www.apnsettings.org/us/us-mobile/))

```
Name : US Mobile
APN : pwg
Proxy : Not Set
Port : Not Set
Username : Not Set
Password : Not Set
Server : Not Set
MMSC : http://pwg.mmsmvno.com/mms/wapenc
MMS Proxy : Not Set
MMS Port : Not Set
MCC : 310
MNC : 260
Authentication Type : Not Set
APN type : default,supl,mms
APN protocol: Ipv4
APN roaming protocol: Ipv4
Enable/disable APN: APN Enabled
Bearer: Unspecified
MVNO type : None
MVNO Value : Not set
```

I don't know if this was necessary to solve my problem but on it's own updating APN did not solve my problem.

However, after I went to Cellular > Cellular Data Options > Voice & Data and switch from LTE to 4G I started to be able to send SMS messages to non iPhones.

Perhaps similar steps can be helpful in resolving people's problem on other carriers.

**NOTE**: That first linked article states:

> For sim cards ordered before 9th June 2021, please make sure Voice and Data are set to 4G and VoLTE OFF. This should resolve the issue temporarily.
> Please get in touch with support so that we can send a replacement sim card for you.

So, apparently, it could be that some people need updated SIM card to be fix their problem.

Answer (score -2):

If your carrier allows it, you can view your APN settings in one of the following locations: Settings > Cellular > Cellular Data Options > Cellular Network. Settings > Mobile Data > Mobile Data Options > Mobile Data Network

[MetroPCS Apn Settings](https://www.apnsettingsandroid.com/2021/08/metropcs-apn-settings-android-ios.html)

[qlink wireless apn settings](https://www.apnsettingsandroid.com/2021/12/qlink-wireless-apn-settings-on-4g5g.html)

Comment: How does this help to solve the problem?